# Wrap an asynchrous function defined elsewhere in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

So I'm dealing with some code right now. There's a `#saveButton` that has a click function attached to it via jQuery:

```
 $("#saveButton").click(function(){
     ...
     if(someCondition){
         $("#addRowsButton").click();
     }
 });
```

The function bound to `#addRowsButton` is defined in a Java Spring tag elsewhere from the function bound to the `#saveButton` is defined. This function makes an Ajax post request. I need to wrap this post request with a callback so that I can make a second post request once it completes. I can easily copy and paste the function body of the `$("#addRowsButton").click();` function to my `#saveButton` function and make my second post call in the callback of the ajax post function. Is there anyway to wrap a click() function with a callback that will not execute the callback until the asynchronous call is done? Seems against async by nature but there might be a way?

Comment: I would still need to wrap that function in a callback that waits until the ajax post receives its response (not just sent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is have the success callback on the first post take a function as the parameter. So you can do this:

```
   function callback2(){ stuff you need done on the second round trip to the server }

   $.ajax(ajax stuff).success(function(callback2){
   //do things you need done on the first trip
   callback2()

   }
```

Comment: I was just thinking something along these lines. Good suggestion. My only question is, if I pass no function, how does my code avoid calling callback2()

Comment: paramets are optional in javascript, so if you don't pass it a parameter it shouldn't be a problem. If you could post a specific example I can give you a more detailed explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. But you can call #addRowsButton's click handler manually, and that handler should return jqXHR value returned from `$.ajax()` call. Then you can use that as a promise to defer second ajax call execution:

```
var addRowsButtonHandler = function() {
    return $.ajax({

        // ajax options

    });
}

$("#saveButton").click(function(){
    ...
    if(someCondition) {

        addRowsButtonHandler().then(function() {
            // second ajax call
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can handle it:

```
        //Fire off the request 
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "script.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {/*Whatever data you pass*/}
        });     

        //Callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
           //Do stuff
        });

        //Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Fail!');
        });
```

Comment: I know how to do this. I'm trying not to have to copy the post part of the code over so that if changes are made to addrowsfunction, I dont have to manage it in two places